# Unique ID variable in Stata

Tags: stata

I am using panel data, and I am trying to merge data sets according to both the `year` and unique `id` variable. However, my `id` variable is not uniform across all the data sets. While, I recognize that this is fundamental to merging data, I am unsure how to tackle this problem.

I am using data for world countries, but not all of the countries are recorded in all data sets. For some there is more countries included. Currently, the data is sorted by the country `id`, which is alphabetically, and each country is assigned a numeric value in Stata. Therefore, some of the countries have different values assigned to them according to how many countries there are in that specific data set. And therefore when I merge the data according to the `id` for each country, and the `year`, these corresponds to different countries.

Is there a way to assign the same number to each country, and make this uniform regardless of the number of countries in the data set?

Comment: You mention "alphabetically", so you do have the country names (in strings), I assume. Are those not the same across the different files? Or do you mean that the names correspond to labels associated with the numeric codes?

Comment: I have them as both strings and also encoded them to correspond to numeric values. i.e.encode var, generate (var1). The strings are the same across the data sets. Currently I have been merging using the encoded variable. And I mean that they are sorted alphabetically by the id. i.e when using the sort command Stata has put them in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

Please provide some attempted code for future questions. Many users here like to **see** some research effort in the form of code.

If I understand correctly all you need to do is `merge` including the string `country` variable in the *key variables* (along with `year`). This corresponds to a simple `merge`; nothing fancy.

An example that uses `state` instead of `country`:

```
*clear all
set more off

*----- example using file -----

sysuse census
keep state pop

gen year = 1999 in 1/25
replace year = 2000 in 25/50

set seed 139476
gen randnum = runiform()
drop if randnum > 0.7
drop randnum

list

tempfile usingf
save "`usingf'"

*----- example main file -----

clear all
sysuse census
keep state death

gen year = 1999 in 1/25
replace year = 2000 in 2/50

set seed 139476
gen randnum = runiform()
drop if randnum > 0.5
drop randnum

list

*----- merge and keep only matching -----

merge 1:1 state year using "`usingf'", keep(match)

order state year
list
```

These two files have some observations that match in the `year`and `state` variables. The latter is a string variable. No need to `encode` beforehand.